# Taking Count of Subqueries in Full Outer Join

Tags: sql-server

I am working on SQL Server 2012. My SQL follows the following structure.

```
SELECT A.attributeA
       ,A.attributeB
       ,Count(A.*) AS CountA  -- I know this is wrong. 
       ,Count(B.*) AS CountB
FROM
(
    SELECT ... FROM Foo1
) A
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT ... FROM Foo2
) B
ON A.attribute1 = B.attribute1
GROUP BY
A.attributeA
,A.attributeB
```

I want to take the count of all rows from subqueries A and B. How do I do that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `COUNT(A.ID)` maybe?

Comment: And you problem is null rows are being thrown out when one side of the join is null? Just do count(1) or count(*) rather than specifying just the columns from one side or the other

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the goal is to just count the non-null records from each side of the join, you can specify the column name (as mentioned in a comment) that you expect to be non-null, often the same column as in your join.  For example, since you joined on attribute1:

```
SELECT A.attributeA
       ,A.attributeB
       ,Count(A.attribute1) AS CountA 
       ,Count(B.attribute1) AS CountB
FROM
...
```

Note that this tells you nothing about when the 2 overlap, if that is part of your goal.  For that type of counting, you can use a SUM combined with CASE:

```
SELECT A.attributeA
       ,A.attributeB
       ,Count(A.attribute1) AS CountA 
       ,Count(B.attribute1) AS CountB
       ,SUM(CASE WHEN A.attribute1 IS NOT NULL AND B.attribute1 IS NOT NULL
                 THEN 1 ELSE 0 
            END) as CountAAndBOverlap
FROM
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is just to get the count of the two sub-queries, you can do something like this one. I've also generated common `ID` for the two sub-queries so that I can `JOIN` them.Lastly, I used `INNER JOIN` instead of `FULL JOIN`.

```
SELECT 
      CountSubqueryA AS CountA,
      CountSubqueryB AS CountB
FROM
(SELECT 1 AS ID,COUNT(*) AS CountSubqueryA FROM Foo1 ) AS A
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT 1 AS ID,COUNT(*) AS CountSubqueryB FROM Foo2 ) AS B
ON A.ID=B.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw your `GROUP BY` and thought maybe you wanted this. It will create up to 3 groups that look something like this:

```
==========================
|   A   | NOT B |   24   |
--------------------------
| NOT A |   B   |   31   |
--------------------------
|   A   |   B   |   69   |
==========================

SELECT
    CASE WHEN A.attribute1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'A' ELSE 'NOT A' END,
    CASE WHEN B.attribute1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'B' ELSE 'NOT B' END
    COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT ... FROM Foo1
) A
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT ... FROM Foo2
) B
ON A.attribute1 = B.attribute1
GROUP BY
    CASE WHEN A.attribute1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'A' ELSE 'NOT A' END,
    CASE WHEN B.attribute1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'B' ELSE 'NOT B' END
```